# 2 Dimensional Array Pointer

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pointers

I am following an example to implement threads in C: http://ramcdougal.com/threads.html.
This example is using a 1-dimensional array. I need a dynamic 2 dimensional array.

What would it look like if in the `main()` it was `int **array` instead of `int array[ARRAYSIZE]`?

My problem is how to pass a pointer to a 2-dimensional array to the struct.
The idea is, that I have a big array, and each thread should only fill a certain area of that array.

Thanks a lot !

Here's the code from the example:

```
struct ThreadData {

    int start, stop;
    int* array;

};


void* squarer(struct ThreadData* td) {


    struct ThreadData* data=(struct ThreadData*) td;
    int start=data->start;
    int stop=data->stop;
    int* array=data->array;
    int i;

    for (i=start; i<stop; i++) {
        array[i]=i*i;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

    int array[ARRAYSIZE];
    pthread_t thread[NUMTHREADS];
    struct ThreadData data[NUMTHREADS];
    int i;

    int tasksPerThread=(ARRAYSIZE+NUMTHREADS-1)/NUMTHREADS;

    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        data[i].start=i*tasksPerThread;
        data[i].stop=(i+1)*tasksPerThread;
        data[i].array=array;
    }
    /* the last thread must not go past the end of the array */
    data[NUMTHREADS-1].stop=ARRAYSIZE;

    /* Launch Threads */
    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, squarer, &data[i]);
    }

    /* Wait for Threads to Finish */
    for (i=0; i<NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    /* Display Result */
    for (i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way:

When working with a one dimensional array, `start` and `stop` are one dimensional vectors representing coordinates in 1-D space (And a 1-D vector can be represented with an integer, which is what the original code uses.)

So in a 2-D array, `start` and `stop` ought to be 2-D vectors:

```
struct ThreadData
{
  int start[2], stop[2];
  int **array;
}
```

Then, you split rectangular blocks amongst the threads. And each thread gets the position of the top left corner of its block in `start`, and the position of the bottom right corner of its block in `stop`.

[image]

*Remember that the blocks, being rectangular, can be tall strips (1 column per thread), or long (one row per thread), or square, or anywhere in between. You have to decide which shape works faster, by benchmarking.*

In a sense, `tasksPerThread` also has two dimensions. With the actual number of tasks becoming `tasksPerThread[0] * tasksPerThread[1]`.

Answer (score 4):

to dynamically allocate 2-dimensional array use something like this:

```
int** array = malloc(sizeof(int*)*ARRAYSIZE);
```

Here you allocate an array of pointers to int, now you should allocate memory for each pointer:

```
for(int i = 0;i<ARRAYSIZE;i++)
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*INNER_ARRAYSIZE);
```

And now fill every entry with your actual data:

```
for(int i = 0;i<ARRAYSIZE;i++)
    for(int j = 0;j<INNER_ARRAYSIZE;j++)
        array[i][j]=(i+j);//just for example
```

And update your ThreadData struct to use two-dimensional arrays:

```
struct ThreadData {

int start, stop;
int** twoDimArray;//note one more * here
```

};

And just pass pointer here:

```
struct ThreadData data;
data.twoDimArray = array;
data.twoDimArray[0][0] = data.twoDimArray[0][0]*data.twoDimArray[0][0]; //access element at 0,0 and square it
```

Comment: doing so make all data non contiguous, thus giving you poor cache performance. better use an Iliffe vector strategy.

Comment: topic starter is trying to follow simple tutorials, let's just keep all the scary C things away for now :)

Comment: it's not a scary C thing, it's basic computer architecture.